# Незнакомый синтаксис в JS (Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Дан пример:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = ss.getSheets()[0];
var destination = ss.getSheets()[1];

var range = source.getRange("B2:D4");
```

Что обозначают квадратные скобки в конце второй и третьей строки(var source = ss.getSheets()[0];) ?

Comment: обращение  к элементу массива...

Answer (score 3):

Функция всегда возвращает какое-то значение, если мы не делаем это руками, то функция автоматом возвращает `undefined`

```
function foo() {

}

const result = foo(); // undefined
```

Можно руками вернуть какое-то значение, например *массив*

```
function foo() {
  return [1, 2, 4];
}

const result = foo(); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Но что если нам нужен только первым элемент массива? Можно сделать так

```
function foo() {
  return [1, 2, 4];
}

const tempResult = foo(); // [1, 2, 3]
const result = tempResult[0];
```

А можно избавиться от лишней переменно, так как `js` позволяет работать с возвращаемым значением сразу же

```
function foo() {
  return [1, 2, 4];
}

const result = foo()[0]; // 1
```

Кстати, сейчас ваш вариант можно переписать по другому ( без доп вызова функции )

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const [source, destination] = ss.getSheets();

const range = source.getRange("B2:D4");
```

Как это работает можно почитать вот [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)